# Split exact sequences: a basic question.

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I am a bit confused regarding the definition of a split exact sequence, whose definition is for example available here (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+exact+sequence).
Let's work in an abelian category, and suppose to have a s.e.s. 
$0 \to B \xrightarrow{f} A \oplus{ B} \xrightarrow{g} A \to 0$
where the maps $f$ and $g$ are *not* supposed to be the inclusion and the projection. Does the sequence split?

I have tried using the universal property of direct sum...but...mmm...I feel as I am missing something. Please, could you help me?

Thank you in advance!
Cheers

Comment: I'm fairly confident the answer is no, but I don't have a counterexample off the top of my head. Is that the answer you were expecting?

Comment: Yes, and actually I was having an idea using the Yoneda isomorphism - but "Crostul" managed to find a simpler counterexample faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample follows in the category of abelian groups. Let $A=\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \Bbb{Z}/2 \Bbb{Z}$, $B = \Bbb{Z}$.

Define $g: B \oplus A \longrightarrow A$ to be the map
$$(z, x_0, x_1,x_2, \dots) \mapsto (z \bmod{2}, x_0, x_1, x_2,  \dots)$$
and $f: B \longrightarrow B \oplus A$ to be the map
$$z \mapsto (2z, 0, 0, 0, \dots) $$

Then $0 \to B \to  B \oplus A \to A \to 0$ is exact and does not split.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you a lot. Cheers